# Exception being thrown incorrectly

Tags: java

I am using pre-written classes from a textbook and implementing them into my program. A duplicate error is being thrown every time I try to add a new element to my tree, and I have no idea why, and I haven't manipulated the written code at all.

Basically, the program prompts the user to enter some information, and will take that info and add it as a student into a binary search tree, I have the following from the textbook:

AbstractBinaryTree Class:

```
public abstract class
AbstractBinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements
BinarySearchTree<E> 

public void add( E element ) {
if ( element == null ) {
  throw new SearchTreeException();
}
setRoot( add( null, this.root(), element ) );
size++;
}
...
```

LinkedBST class:

```
public class LinkedBST<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends
AbstractBinarySearchTree<E> {

public LinkedBST( E element ) {
if ( element == null ) {
  throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException( "null element is illegal" );
}
this.root = new BSTNode<E> ( element );
this.size = 1;
}

protected void setRoot( BSTNode<E> newRoot ) {
this.root = newRoot;
}

protected BSTNode<E> add( BSTNode<E> parent, BSTNode<E> node, E element ) {
if ( node == null ) { // base case
  node = new BSTNode<E> ( element );
  node.parent = parent;
}
else { // recursive case
  int compareResult = element.compareTo( node.element );
  if ( compareResult < 0 ) { // recursive case - left
    node.leftChild = add( node, node.leftChild, element );
  }
  else if ( compareResult > 0 ) { // recursive case - right
    node.rightChild = add( node, node.rightChild, element );
  }
  else {
    throw new SearchTreeException( "Duplicate element: " + element.toString() );
  }
}

return node;
}
 ...
```

as well as `BinarySearchTree` interface, and then where I'm actually calling the method from a seperate class:

```
...
AbstractBinarySearchTree<Student> tree = new LinkedBST<Student>(); //this could be a problem?
...
tree.add(new Student(studentNumber, firstName, lastName, major, gpa));
```

So, I know this partially works at least. I'm able to add at least one record into the tree, but when I try to add a second one regardless of the information, it keeps throwing a `SearchTreeException` a(also pre written) and won't add any others. I am still really new to abstract classes as well as binary search trees so I am doing my best at implementing this, so if anyone can see where I am going wrong that would be awesome!

Comment: How have you implemented the `compareTo` method on your `Student` class?

Comment: Probably incorrectly ha, I have `public class Student implements Comparable<Student>` and then just auto-imported the compareTo method, didnt actually do anything to it tho...

Comment: Does it return `0`? Look at your `add` implementation. Where does it throw the exception?

Comment: yeah its this: @Override
 public int compareTo(Student arg0) {  return 0;
 }

Comment: and the exception is being thrown from `throw new SearchTreeException( "Duplicate element: " + element.toString() );` in the LinkedBST class

Comment: should it not return 0? what should that look like instead?

Comment: Right: the SearchTreeException isn't letting you add duplicates, and your compareTo function is always returning 0 (which is what compareTo returns when two things are the same), so your code always sees duplicates - what you need to do is actually implement the compareTo by specifying when two Students should or shouldn't be considered the same. (Probably by comparing "studentNumber").

Comment: @xTopShelfx In general: "-1" for less then, (+)"1" for greater then and "0" for equality.

Comment: Associated documentation on the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) interface.

Comment: got it working thank you for your help! If you want to answer is @SotiriosDelimanolis I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Comparable` interface and its [`compareTo(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method, it states

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

If you're seeing a `SearchTreeException`, it means this piece of code

```
int compareResult = element.compareTo( node.element );
if ( compareResult < 0 ) { // recursive case - left
    node.leftChild = add( node, node.leftChild, element );
}
else if ( compareResult > 0 ) { // recursive case - right
    node.rightChild = add( node, node.rightChild, element );
}
else {
    throw new SearchTreeException( "Duplicate element: " + element.toString() );
}
```

used your implementation of `compareTo(..)` which returned a `0`.

From the comments, you stated you were using the default (IDE-)created implementation of the method which always returns `0`. You need to fix this so that your `compareTo` method works as documented in the javadoc.